# 'kubectl top pods' Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, kubectl, kubernetes-apiserver

When I am trying to run `kubectl top nodes` I`m getting the output:

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)
```

Metric server is able to scrape the metrics, in the logs getting the metrics

```
ScrapeMetrics: time: 49.754499ms, nodes: 4, pods: 82

...Storing metrics...

...Cycle complete...
```

But the end points for the metrics service are missing, how can i resolve this issue?

```
kubectl get apiservices |egrep metrics

v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io   kube-system/metrics-server   False (MissingEndpoints)
```

any help will be appriciated!

Comment: Can you add the output of `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` and `kubectl describe -n kube-system pod <name-of-your-metrics-server-pod>` to your question?

Comment: The issue here is similar to the one raised in other stack posts and has been answered. Refer to the links[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811388/error-from-server-serviceunavailable-the-server-is-currently-unable-to-handle?rq=1) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138734/metric-server-not-working-unable-to-handle-the-request-get-nodes-metrics-k8s?rq=1) or if your issue got resolved, please post the  procedure you have followed.