# Metric server not working : unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-metrics

I am running command **kubectl top nodes** and getting error :

```
node@kubemaster:~/Desktop/metric$ kubectl top nodes
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)
```

Metric Server pod is running with following params :

```
    command:
    - /metrics-server
    - --metric-resolution=30s
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=aggregator
    - --kubelet-insecure-tls
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,Hostname,InternalDNS,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP
```

Most of the answer I am getting is the above params,
Still getting error

```
E0601 18:33:22.012798       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:kubemaster: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet kubemaster (192.168.56.30): Get https://192.168.56.30:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: context deadline exceeded, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:kubenode1: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet kubenode1 (192.168.56.31): Get https://192.168.56.31:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: dial tcp 192.168.56.31:10250: i/o timeout]
```

I have deployed metric server using :

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.3.6/components.yaml
```

What am I missing?
Using Calico for Pod Networking

On github page of metric server under FAQ:

```
[Calico] Check whether the value of CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR in the calico.yaml conflicts with the local physical network segment. The default: 192.168.0.0/16.
```

Could this be the reason. Can someone explains this to me.

I have setup Calico using : 
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.14/manifests/calico.yaml

My Node Ips are : 192.168.56.30  / 192.168.56.31 / 192.168.56.32

I have initiated the cluster with --pod-network-cidr=20.96.0.0/12. So my pods Ip are 20.96.205.192 and so on.

Also getting this in apiserver logs

```
E0601 19:29:59.362627       1 available_controller.go:420] v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io failed with: failing or missing response from https://10.100.152.145:443/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: Get https://10.100.152.145:443/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

where 10.100.152.145 is IP of service/metrics-server(ClusterIP)

Surprisingly it works on another cluster with Node Ip in 172.16.0.0 range.
Rest everything is same. Setup using kudeadm, Calico, same pod cidr

Comment: can you just leave `- --kubelet-insecure-tls` and `- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP`?

Comment: Tried but not working,

Comment: Idk then mate. I have deployed metrics server 100 times, and always started with this issue. You can set `- --v=4` for more verbose output from the logs.

Comment: Addresses within subnet 20.96.0.0/12 are public addresses so maybe this is why it is failing.

Answer (score 20):

It started working after I edited the metrics-server deployment yaml config to include a DNS policy.

**hostNetwork: true**

[image: Click here to view the image description]

Refer to the link below:
https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/service-unavailable-kubernetes-metrics/

Comment: Don't forget to restart a metrics pod ;) In my case it was needed.

Answer (score 1):

Default value of Calico net is 192.168.0.0/16
There is a comment in yaml file:

> The default IPv4 pool to create on startup if none exists. Pod IPs
> will be chosen from this range. Changing this value after installation
> will have no effect. This should fall within `--cluster-cidr`.
>
> - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR   value: "192.168.0.0/16"

So, its better use different one if your home network is contained in 192.168.0.0/16.

Also, if you used kubeadm you can check your cidr in k8s:

```
kubeadm config view | grep Subnet
```

Or you can use kubectl:

```
kubectl  --namespace kube-system get configmap kubeadm-config -o yaml
```

Default one in kubernetes "selfhosted" is 10.96.0.0/12

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue in my on-prem k8s v1.26 (cni=calico).
I thinks that this issue because of Metric-Server version (v0.6).
I solved my issue by apply Metric-Server v5.0.2

1- Download [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.5.2/components.yaml) Yaml file from official source

2- add ( - --kubelet-insecure-tls=true ) bellow the -args section

3- apply yaml

enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to run metrics on docker desktop and I followed @suren's answer and it worked.
The default configuration is:

```
- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,Hostname,InternalDNS,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP
```

And I changed to:

```
- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```