# Failed to install metrics-server on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, metrics-server

I am trying to install metrics-server on my Kubernetes cluster. But it is not going to READY mode.

I am was installed metrics-server in this method

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

[image]

After installing i was tried some of those commands, kubectl top pods, kubectl top nodes. But i got an error

**Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)**

Metrics server is failed to start

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138734/metric-server-not-working-unable-to-handle-the-request-get-nodes-metrics-k8s check this thread

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Metric server not working : unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138734/metric-server-not-working-unable-to-handle-the-request-get-nodes-metrics-k8s)

Comment: I am fixed it, using the command `minikube addons enable metrics-server`

Comment: can you post your own answer based on  results? It will be easier in future for new people find the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable metrics-server addon in minikube cluster.

Try the following commend.

```
minikube addons enable metrics-server
```

Comment: Works as of May 2023!